# Julia local variable not defined in expression eval

Tags: julia, eval, metaprogramming

Given the following function,

```
function floop(exp)
    a = 5
    b = 10
    ex = Expr(:call, :+, 1, exp);
    return eval(ex);
end
```

if I then run

```
floop(Symbol("b"))
```

I get an error saying that `b` is not defined. Why does this not work? How can I make this work?

Comment: I would suggest reading up on macros: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/index.html#man-macros-1

Comment: @Mason Why do you suggest this? Will a macro be able to fulfill this role?

Comment: Yes a macro can do what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the key things that lets Julia be fast is that eval always runs in the global scope. This means it can never refer to local variables.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the following macro, choosing a value at expansion time, depending on a statically known `Symbol`:

```
julia> macro floop(selector::QuoteNode)
           choices = Dict(:a => 5, :b => 10)
           ex = :(1 + $(choices[selector.value]))
           return ex
       end
@floop (macro with 1 method)

julia> @macroexpand @floop(:a)
:(1 + 5)

julia> @macroexpand @floop(:b)
:(1 + 10)

julia> @floop(:c)
ERROR: LoadError: KeyError: key :c not found
Stacktrace:
 [1] getindex(::Dict{Symbol,Int64}, ::Symbol) at ./dict.jl:477
 [2] @floop(::LineNumberNode, ::Module, ::QuoteNode) at ./REPL[27]:3
in expression starting at REPL[33]:1

julia> s = :a; @floop(s)
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching @floop(::LineNumberNode, ::Module, ::Symbol)
Closest candidates are:
  @floop(::LineNumberNode, ::Module, ::QuoteNode) at REPL[1]:2
in expression starting at REPL[2]:1
```

It's up to you how to actually store the actual values.  A `const` global dictionary would be an option, or just a simple `if` chain.

(There can actually be other things than a `Symbol` in a `QuoteNode`, but it's difficult to splice them into the macro call, and they would also just raise a `KeyError`, so I didn't include any extra handling of that.)